# what does cv2.normalize actually do when we pass a threshold image of mask?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am going through someones code,i am not getting few things:

1. after creating a mask for barcode in some brands tag, what is the need to create a threshold image of that mask (because when we see image it looks same)and
2. then that thresholded image is normalized using the cv2.normalize(), what would normalize function actually do

#### 1) creating a mask:

```
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("/home/nayantara/Desktop/beinghuman.jpg")
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype = "uint8")
cv2.rectangle(mask, (700, 1038), (1733 , 2111),(255,255,255),-1)
```

#### 2) getting threshold of mask :

```
ret,barcode_mask_thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

#### 3) normalizing the threshold image :

```
cropped_barcode_mask = cv2.normalize(src=barcode_mask_thresh, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you have a thresholded image which was done by

```
ret,barcode_mask_thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

You will have only 2 possible values, either 0 or 255 (for this case at least). Then, when you do the normalization with `NORM_MIN_MAX` you will get the minimum and maximum value of the array/image and re scale the array so that the minimum value is the minimum value possible and the maximum value will be the maximum value possible.

As an example consider the following array of numbers:

```
eg = np.array([10, 20, 30, 10, 45, 90])
```

If we do the normalization, the algorithm will scale them to fit the complete range, this means, 10 which is the minimum will be the minimum possible which 0 and 90 the maximum which is 255. If we do:

```
cv2.normalize(eg, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255,norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
```

we get:

```
array([[  0], [ 32], [ 64], [  0], [112], [255]], dtype=uint8)
```

Going back to your specific case, you can have only 2 possible numbers, which are already the possible minimum and possible maximum, which leads to 3 possible scenarios.

**1) You have 0 and 255 in the array**, it will be like:

```
eg = np.array([0, 255, 0, 255, 255])
cv2.normalize(eg, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255,norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
```

which gives:

```
array([[  0], [ 255], [ 0], [  255], [255]], dtype=uint8)
```

**2) All numbers are 0** the minimum and maximum are the same and the result will be an array of 0.

**3) All numbers are 255**, the minimum and maximum are the same and once again it will give only 0.

---

Bottom line, the function is basically useless for this case, unless that you want to convert a completely white image into a black one (all numbers are 255 and convert it to 0) in any other case the result will be exactly the same, therefore it is not needed.